# I want to have a delimiter at end of a tr in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have a delimiter as comma for separation of a cell and a delimiter for end of a `tr` in a HTML table using jQuery. Also I have all these rows as a checked checkbox. I am currently using the below function:

```
var values = new Array();

$.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"), function () {
  values.push($(this).text());
});

alert("val---" + values.join(", "));
```

Comment: Your code appears to be doing what you require already. Is there an issue with it?

Comment: It's doing the cell separation but how to achieve row separation?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the HTML table you have, and also the text output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if i have 
A B
C D
E F
then i am looking for A,B;C,D;E,f;

Comment: So you want `,` to delimit cells and `;` to delimit rows, is that correct?

Comment: yes you got it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I have `A B C D E F` then I am looking for `A,B;C,D;E,F`

In this case you need two loops; one through the rows and another through the cells. Each loop can build an array of the values and then be joined by `,` and `;` respectively. Try this:

```js
var output = $('table tr:has(:checkbox:checked)').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find('td:not(:first)').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(',')];
}).get().join(';');

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="true" /></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="true" /></td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You got it correct but one ore thing we need to have a check which row is checked with a checkbox.

Comment: I updated the answer for you. Note that the second row is excluded as the checkbox is not checked by default

Comment: Thanks Rory for your help